# How to zip 2 strings into a new string in python

Tags: python, string, zip

I am try to figure out how to zip two strings of different length into one string alternating the chars and preserving the leftover chars in the longer string. Example:

```
a = '12345'
b = 'abcdefgh'
```

I tried `zip(a,b)` but it returns a list of tuples and cuts off when there aren't equal length strings:

```
[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'd'), ('5', 'e')]
```

I need to get just the new string out. Example:

```
result = 1a2b3c4d5efgh
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a for loop? Starting at position 0 of each and adding each letter onto a third new string. Have i and k be the lengths of the two strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way: join the inner tuples and then the outer list.

```
''.join(''.join(x) for x in zip(a,b))
```

Though, `zip()` will always stop aggregating when the shortest beween `a` and `b` ends (`1a2b3c4d5e` in your example). If you want to reach the end of the longest input string you must iterate them differently, for example:

```
c = [] 
for x in range(max(len(a),len(b))):
    c.append(a[x] if x < len(a) else '')
    c.append(b[x] if x < len(b) else '')
result=''.join(c)
```

Or, as suggested by Moinuddin below, using `izip_longest`:

```
''.join(''.join(x) for x in izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=''))
```

**NOTE** that as of Python 3, `izip_longest()` is now `zip_longest()`.

Comment: how would you get this to preserve the remaining chars in the bigger string

Comment: @smitty - i edited the answer. if you want to preserve the end, zip is not the way to go...

Comment: @smitty In that case, use `itertools.izip_longest()` it will fill the smaller list's values with `None`